# Does Android support the Exchange ActiveSync policy "Encrypt storage card"?

Tags: sd-card, encryption, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, active-sync

Without middleware, without Google Apps, does Android support the Exchange ActiveSync policy "encrypt storage card."?

[According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Exchange_ActiveSync_clients), Android doesn't support the ActiveSync command to encrypt a storage card. I'd like a second opinion, with a reference.

PS: I've seen Samsung [claim the ability to encrypt storage cards](http://androidcommunity.com/verizon-rolls-out-droid-charge-gingerbread-ota-update-20111130/), but unless it's through ActiveSync, it's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to Android 3.0 (Honeycomb), Android did not natively supported encrypting local storage at all. [Android 3.0 introduced the ability to encrypt the local device](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-3.0-highlights.html#enterprise), and to enforce device encryption by Activesync policy.

Other than the Galaxy Nexus, every phone currently on the market is running either a 1.x or 2.x version of Android, none of these support device or removable media encryption in the Android OS, it is possible that some manufacturers may have added encryption, but this isn't a standard part of the OS available to standard ActiveSync implementations.

For Android 4.x phones (currently only the Galaxy Nexus) [full device encryption (and the relevant policies) is brought to phones](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-4.0-highlights.html#communication-dev) but this still doesn't seem to include removable media.

Answer (score 1):

On my Samsung Galaxy S2, adding corporate exchange/ActiveSync account does indeed force encryption of all device storage.

Answer (score 1):

A number of Motorola devices support that feature. Here is a [link](http://www.motorola.com/Business-Ready/US-EN/Business-Ready-Support-Pages/Security) to their site. My group has the Bionic and Atrix 2 and they support that feature.